# Comments editor not rendering &nbsp and <br> tag

Tags: comments, html

WordPress comments editor rendering all other html tags but not rendering br tag and displaying &nbsp as it is on the front end.
I have already tried [WP Editor comments Plus plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-editor-comments-plus/) without any luck.

It is important to render all html tags because my client wants to send these comments to post author via email. I ll need someone help to fix this issue.
Your help will  be much appreciated. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The standard comment form functionality renders the br tag and &nbsp on the front end. You can see this in the image below (which uses Divi).
[image: br and nbsp tags in wordpress]

You might want to check the comments.php file on your theme if you find a different behavior for your comments text. Alternatively, if I have not understood the question, please advise.

Comment: I am working in genesis framework and for me &nbsp displaying on front end as it is. I could not see &nbsp in above attached image.